# Reporting from fact-less fact tables and/or junk dimensions - flat reporting, no aggregates - Kimball

Tags: sql-server, pivot-table, data-warehouse, cube, dimensional-modeling

I am trying to add some fact-less fact tables and/or junk dimension tables to a Kimball-style Data Warehouse, but I struggle to understand how to report from such tables once they are added to cubes and when the cubes are queried from Excel for example (Pivot tables).

Here's the scenario:

A property services company offers mortgage services. When a prospect customer is interested in obtaining a mortgage, a Case is opened and various processes take place before a mortgage (and other potential products) are offered to the customer.

(For each Case, there may be multiple business processes that are modelled by separate, transactional fact tables (containing additive measures), but we are not going to focus on those here as they are easy to model)

What I am struggling with is modelling the Case process itself (which is the umbrella term for everything that happens, from a business point of view, when the case is being progressed by the mortgage broker). Cases contain various flags (and text fields) that get set by the user in the OLTP system. Users want to be able to report on cases, and list the values for all of those flags, text fields etc. without any measures/aggregations as such. 
So if I use a fact-less fact table and a junk dimension for the flags, we would have some like this:

**DimDate**

```
 DateKey     Date          Year     Month    etc. 
 20150101    01/01/2015    2015     1
 20150102    02/01/2015    2015     1
 20150103    03/01/2015    2015     1
 etc.
```

**DimCustomer**

```
 CustomerKey     CustomerName
 1               J Smith
 2               B Edwards
 3               A Davies
 etc.
```

**DimCaseIndicator**

```
 IndicatorKey     HasWillFlag     HasHomeInsuranceFlag
 1                True            True
 2                True            False
 3                False           True
 etc.
```

**FactCase**

```
 CaseOpenedDateKey  CaseSubmittedDateKey  IdCase(BusinessKey)  CustomerKey  IndicatorKey
 20150101           20150102              ABC1234              1            2
 20150101           20150101              ABC1235              2            3
```

Now, to display a flattened report (1 row per case) we could run the following SQL against the above tables directly in the Data Warehouse as follows:

```
 SELECT FactCase.IdCase,
        DimCustomer.CustomerName,
        DimIndicator.HasWillFlag,
        DimIndicator.HasHomeInsuranceFlag
        etc.
 FROM FactCase 
 JOIN DimCustomer on FactCase.CustomerKey = DimCustomer.CustomerKey
 JOIN DimIndicator ON FactCase.IndicatorKey = DimIndicator.IndicatorKey
 etc.
```

This would give us:

```
 IdCase     CustomerName     HasWillFlag     HasHomeInsuranceFlag
 ABC1234    J Smith          True            False
 ABC1235    B Edwards        False           True
```

However, how would we achieve the same output if the above tables were included in a cube and if we were using Excel to query the cube? 
When I try to do that, Pivot table in Excel wants to aggregate (and rightly so!), but what I want is a flat report as above.

Comment: Simply put: do not use cubes for transactional reporting. The best you can do is put a dummy measure in and zero suppress it to only show only the rows you want but this is a classic mistake. Why do you feel you need to use a cube for this?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The reason I felt that I needed to use a cube is that if we want all reporting to be done from a Data Warehouse (Kimball-style data warehouse, to be clear) and users do almost all reporting from cubes built on top of the Data Warehouse, then how would you implement reporting like the one above? Would users go for aggregates to cubes and for operational (transactional) reporting to SSRS for example (where someone would have written SQL like the one above to produce flat reports)?

Comment: Ideally it's transparent. You have one report called 'Case Statuses' or something which is a relational report. Summary type reports come out of other reports which happen to access the cube. The user doesn't know the difference if their access point is a report. If you want interactive analysis cubes are great but you are describing an actual report here

Comment: Ok, makes perfect sense. One last question though: for 'relational' reports, would you still report from a data warehouse? Would you go through the whole pain of ETL etc. to get data from source system(s) and load into dimensional tables in DW, even though some of these tables are not going to be used by cubes? Or would relational reports be typically run directly from OLTP systems? My gut feeling is that ideally, all reporting should be done from a data warehouse... but Kimball does not mention in his book(s) how fact-less fact tables are actually used (i.e.whether they are included in cubes)

Comment: DW's do a lot more than just provide data for cubes. You don't even need a DW for a cube because you can load operational data directly into cubes. DW's provide a data model that is easier to report from, whether relationally or from a cube. The only good reason to not load data into a DW (within an organisation that has one) is for real time type reporting where you need operational data very quickly in some kind of real time dashboard.

Comment: Oh yeah, of course DW does more than just cubes, my understanding is that DW should be the 'one stop shop' for reporting (be it from cubes or directly from DW). The only thing is - some data is difficult to model dimensionally and all we sometimes need is a flat table!

Comment: Yep I agree, sometimes things are difficult to model in a star schema. There is always a time/budget/quality triangle. If you do not have enough time or budget to do it, the quality loses out, i.e. you build things that are no longer in a star schema. However having a consistent approach is very important because when your datawarehouse has 1000's of objects (reports, tables, views, ETL etc.), it makes it easier if its built consistently. Perhaps you should have on ODS layer below the star schema, which is a replication of the source sytem and you can report out of there

Comment: So data goes: `1. Many source systems > 2. ODS > 3. Star Schema > 4. Cubes`, and you build reports out of the appropriate layer

Comment: Is the ODS layer just a set of OLTP databases (restored from Live backups, say, every night)?

Comment: Say, for instance, if we have a dedicated, stand-alone BI server, I guess we could have several SQL instances on it like this: [servername]\ODS   (this is were all OLTP databases would get restored in their original form every night),   [servername]\Staging  (used by ETL jobs for loads into start schema), and then [servername]\DW which would be the star-schema DW ?

Comment: Yes you can split them up any way you like. They can be different databases on a single instance or they can be in different schemas inside a single database. If you keep them all on one instance though it's _far_ easier to do cross-database operations than it is to do cross-server operations. So I would suggest you keep them on the same server. Only downside is you can't allocate memory at the database level.... but just have loads of memory so you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Yes ODS is a copy of live databases. This might be populated from backups (i.e. nightly) or it might be trickle fed with differential replication (i.e. every 5 minutes). Depends how much latency is OK

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you added all those 4 columns from your cube in Excel it would give you the same output as the flattened report you describe. What would it be aggregating over?
Ideally you'd have a count measure in your cube also.